# Java: JSONObject inheritance

Tags: java, json, inheritance

I'm having trouble converting objects into JSONObject (org.json.JSONObject) in java.

I have an object X that is a child object Y. When I make "new JSONObject (this).ToString()", only the attributes of the object X (child) that are created in the JSONObject.

See an example below:

Parent Class:

```
import org.json.JSONObject; 

public class Class1 {
private String name;
private int number;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
public String toString(){
    return new JSONObject(this).toString(); 
}
}
```

Child class:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class Class2 extends Class1 {

private String attrChildString;
private int attrChildInt;
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();
    class2.setName("test");
    class2.setNumber(5);
    class2.setAttrChildInt(10);
    class2.setAttrChildString("child");

    System.out.println("toString child : " + class2.toString());
    System.out.println("toString Parent : " + class2.toStringParent());
}
public String getAttrChildString() {
    return attrChildString;
}
public void setAttrChildString(String attrChildString) {
    this.attrChildString = attrChildString;
}
public int getAttrChildInt() {
    return attrChildInt;
}
public void setAttrChildInt(int attrChildInt) {
    this.attrChildInt = attrChildInt;
}

public String toString(){
    return new JSONObject(this).toString(); 
}

public String toStringParent(){
    return super.toString();
} 
}
```

**Result:** toString child : {"attrChildInt":10,"attrChildString":"child"}
            toString Parent : {"attrChildInt":10,"attrChildString":"child"}

But I need to display the values ​​of the parent.
**Example:**  {"attrChildInt":10,"attrChildString":"child","name":"test","number":"5"}

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding an `@Override` annotation to make sure the `toString()` method is overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, just copied your code to my Eclipse, added the sources from http://json.org/java to the project, executed and here's what I get:

```
toString child : {"attrChildInt":10,"name":"test","number":5,"attrChildString":"child"}
toString Parent : {"attrChildInt":10,"name":"test","number":5,"attrChildString":"child"}
```

I'm on Java 6 and used [this implementation of JSONObject](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/zipball/master)

Comment: I am using apache-tomcat-7.0.20\lib\json-20080701.jar (http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/versionInfo/21653). I tryed using Gson and code this https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/zipball/master  and 2 options worked fine. The problem must be even-20080701.jar.

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it takes field defined in object, and not in superclasses. Just grab another databilding tool (there is a ton of them  - for example GSON  , xstream., my own databiding: https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer  )

Answer (score 0):

This must have been true at the time of asking this question, however, they have apparently fixed this bug in later versions. I used json 20180130 and it worked just fine.